# Can not Remove Archives and Meta from Sidebar

Tags: theme-development, templates, sidebar

This should be easy right? Removing Archives and Meta from the sidebars of two of my main WP pages. I can't seem to! I've looked in **Appearance > Widgets** and made sure Archives and Meta was not appearing in any fields. I have checked my Theme's ([Fruitful](https://wordpress.org/themes/fruitful/)) options in Customizer--playing with the width layout, and I have tried diddle dallying with some of the PHP files and CSS to see if I could remove by deleting some things. Deleting is the most I can do. Since I am no means a code writer.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have any menus in "Appearances->Menus" that has Archives and Meta?

Answer (score 1):

The theme is set up so that if a sidebar is inactive, default content will be shown (search form, monthly archives, and meta).

For example, the `sidebar.php` file:

```
<?php
/**
 * The Sidebar containing the main widget areas.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Fruitful theme
 * @since Fruitful theme 1.0
 */
?>
<div id="secondary" class="widget-area" role="complementary">
    <?php do_action( 'before_sidebar' ); ?>
    <?php if ( ! dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' ) ) : ?>

        <aside id="search" class="widget widget_search">
            <?php get_search_form(); ?>
        </aside>

        <aside id="archives" class="widget">
            <h1 class="widget-title"><?php _e( 'Archives', 'fruitful' ); ?></h1>
            <ul>
                <?php wp_get_archives( array( 'type' => 'monthly' ) ); ?>
            </ul>
        </aside>

        <aside id="meta" class="widget">
            <h1 class="widget-title"><?php _e( 'Meta', 'fruitful' ); ?></h1>
            <ul>
                <?php wp_register(); ?>
                <li><?php wp_loginout(); ?></li>
                <?php wp_meta(); ?>
            </ul>
        </aside>

    <?php endif; // end sidebar widget area ?>
</div><!-- #secondary .widget-area -->
```

You can override the theme's `sidebar.php` file by creating a [child theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) and adding your own customized `sidebar.php` file to it. E.g.:

```
<?php
/**
 * The Sidebar containing the main widget areas.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Fruitful child theme
 * @since Fruitful child theme 1.0
 */
?>

<div id="secondary" class="widget-area" role="complementary">
    <?php do_action( 'before_sidebar' ); ?>
    <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' ); ?>
</div><!-- #secondary .widget-area -->
```

The theme uses several sidebars (`sidebar.php`, `sidebar-blogright.php`, `sidebar-homepage.php`, `sidebar-page.php`, `sidebar-single-post.php` plus the store related sidebars, which are set up differently) so follow this procedure for each sidebar that you would like to modify using the appropriate sidebar name when calling `dynamic_sidebar()`.

Answer (score 1):

Updated for 2020,

Goto Appearance ---> Customize ---> Widget
**(Note: If there is no APPEARANCE OPTION click on DESIGN and CUSTOMIZE)**

[image]

Next Click on ADD WIDGETS. Notice that side navigation is present.

[image]

After clicking on ADD WIDGET, scroll down the list to NAVIGATION MENU and select it.

[image]

Notice that side pane navigation is gone. You don't have to add nothing to NAVIGATION MENU. LEAVE IT BLANK. CLICK  SAVE CHANGES.

I handle my navigation by text hyperlinks within the body of my page by highlighting text content. Gives cleaner appearance in my opinion.

[image]