# Need to delete the sidebar widget area and have the page a full page rather than just have a blank widget area

Tags: widgets, sidebar

A recent post on how to remove the archives and meta from the sidebar answered a question I had and I was successful to have the left side of the page blank. The post was at [Can not Remove Archives and Meta from Sidebar](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/254016/can-not-remove-archives-and-meta-from-sidebar).

But, while it left the sidebar area void of text, I need the sidebar area to be deleted so it's a full page. I have some pricing tables that I want to be the only thing on the page but due to the template in WorkScout, the pricing tables are on the right side of the page leaving a lot of white space on the left side where the widgets were. I have tried configuring the page to be "full page using Elementor" which has worked in the past for other needs, but, it is not creating the full page I need for this pricing table page.

Am I missing a step or is this not possible? How can I delete the old widget area and have it full page.

I am new to Wordpress so I appreciate the help and will appreciate step by step instructions.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: This heavily depends on what you're using as the theme; is it a custom theme, someone else's theme, did you build a child theme?  Some themes will include full width and sidebar templates that you can assign to different pages, etc.  It really depends so providing more info is going to be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to make pages full width. In your case you just have deleted the sidebar widget but the sidebar is still exist. So if you have any template full width in your theme you can simply assign to the page.

If you are using elementor, you can use full width template by selecting page attribute
[image]

The other way is to copy page.php into tp-full-width.php. on the top of tpl-full-width.php assign any name

```
<?php /* Template Name: Full Width */ ?>
```

Now assign the template to the page you want as page attribute mentioned about in the image

Hope That work for you

Comment: Thank you! I did change the page to full page Elementor but now my upper section that showed the page name and navigation disappeard. Hmm... But, it did give me a full page. Back to the drawing board.  This is WorkScout and while it's suppose to be a great template, it has very poor documentation or tutorials so for someone not well versed in Wordpress, it's confusing. I appreciate your fast response very much!

Comment: In Such case you should try the second method to copy page template to new one and on the top name it in comment whatever you like. In this template remove sidebar() code and make it full width.

Comment: Thank you Atif. I appreciate your response!

Comment: ask me if you need any help